# Codeigniter 3.0 dando 404 not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu instalei o **CodeIgniter 3.0** em meu apache e quando tenho acessar http://localhost/Azzunet/login ele me retorna `error 404 not found`. Os arquivos do `controller` está correto e `views` também (só tem HTML). O que acontece para dar esse problema na versão 3.0 ?

**login.php** (controller)

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
}
```

Comment: `http://localhost/Azzunet` te direciona para o controller de boas vindas?

Comment: Também tive este problema e EU consegui resolver colocando a primeira letra do nome do arquivo seja ele um controller, model e view em maiúscula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Codeigniter 3 exige que o nome dos arquivos do controller comecem com letra maiúscula.

Na sua pasta `controllers`, renomeie o arquivo `login.php` para `Login.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Três casos:

1. Verifique se no seu arquivo `routes.php`, você definiu sua rota principal, caso seja na classe `Login`
2. Verifique se o `index.php` está "atrapalhando"

   - Acesse sua url da seguinte forma: `http://localhost/Azzunet/index.php/login`
   - Ou na raiz do seu projeto, inclua o código descrito nesse link  http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html#removing-the-index-php-file e salve-o com o nome `.htaccess` para remover o `index.php` da sua url (além de que você também deve remove-lo também da configuração do arquivo `config.php`)
3. Construtor

   - Inclua o construtor da classe com a chamada `parent::__construct();`

Comment: Fiz tudo isso e nada. Continua dando 404. O CI 2.2 funciona de boa

Comment: Veja a última alteração acima!

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema e só consigo acessar colocando o index.php/login

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso o problema começou a dar quando migrei o site para um novo ambiente, e começou a dar 404 em todas as subpáginas. O problema era configuração do Apache.

Editei o httpd.conf, substituindo todas as instâncias de **AllowOverride None** para **AllowOverride All** (linhas 231 e 268 no meu caso). Reinicei o Apache e tudo funcionou normalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Dois anos atrasado, mas vai que alguém procura uma solução e cai aqui.
Sendo assim, lá vai.

Verifique se você não tem um controller com o mesmo nome da sub-pasta. 
Eu tinha o seguinte, 
controller/site/programasDOsite.php
controller/crm/programasDOcrm.php

quando criei um controller/crm.php, ele deixou de acessar as pasta controller/crm/programasDOcrm.php